# Is this the correct way of making a callback like jQuery does it for non-blocking code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, callback

Excuse me if this is very basic, but i want to know if i have really understood how i can create a non-blocking function with a callback.

The basic example:

**JS**

```
MyFunc('value',function(data) {
    $('body').append(data);
});

function MyFunc(value, callback)
{
    $.post('Fetch.php', {param1: value}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

**PHP (Fetch.php)**

```
echo json_encode($_POST['param1']);
```

Will this classify as the appropriate way to construct a function with callback? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. The only thing is that jQuery will likely parse response for you so you can even shorten your code to `$.post('Fetch.php', {param1: value}, callback);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is correct way to work with callbacks. The only thing is that jQuery will likely parse response for you so you can even shorten your code to

```
function MyFunc(value, callback) {
    $.post('Fetch.php', {param1: value}, callback);
}
```

> Is there a better way to do it?

Another approach (more flexible and powerful) is to return promise object from your function:

```
function MyFunc(value) {
    return $.post('Fetch.php', {param1: value});
}

MyFunc('value').then(function(data) {
    $('body').append(data);
});
```

Comment: Elegant, spot on and simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery code runs synchronously (blocking) as until HTML5 there was no multithreading support in JS. The javascript itself though won't block the UI. I believe certain methods of the WIP libraries may utilise web workers (async) but I am not sure.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP's question is about creating AJAX requests that don't block the UI, not about running JavaScript code in another thread.

Comment: An Ajax request wont block the UI as if you [look at the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) async execution of Ajax is enabled by default.